# Opening Spotify from URI with Cordova in Meteor

Tags: android, html, cordova, meteor, uri

I am running a meteor app on my Android phone with cordova. In my HTML I have a link set to open up a specific spotify uri:

```
<a href="spotify:artist:5lsC3H1vh9YSRQckyGv0Up">link to spotify</a>
```

I want my app to open up the native spotify app at this specific artist. In a browser like chrome this works as expected. However within my cordova app it doesn't open anything.

Anyone has an idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :D

You can add this cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

It allows you to use this syntax:

```
<a onclick="window.open('spotify:artist:5lsC3H1vh9YSRQckyGv0Up', '_system');">link</a>
```

This will work in Meteor